# Parse array with nested objects by given indexes , get their name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

Link to sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-northcutt-7c9sr

I have a catalog with furniture and I need to make dynamic breadcrumbs. There is an array with nested objects which 5 levels deep. When I'm rendering list of furniture, I 'm saving all indexes from which array this list.

Expected output: Using my  indexes, I need to parse object with nested array , get name of each object where belongs that index and save it in array

Indexes that I saved when user clicked on inventories . Key is a object name and property is actual index.

```
menuIndexes : {
  buildings: 0,
  building_styles: 3,
  rooms: 2,
  room_fillings: 0,
  filling_types: 1,
}
```

That piece of data , where i'm rendering from  list of furniture . Name property is a name of a link in menu

```
{
  buildings: [
    {
      name: 'office',
      building_styles: [
        {
          name: 'interior',
          rooms: [
            {
              name: 'open space',
              filling_types: [
                {
                  name: 'furniture',
                  room_fillings: [
                    {
                      name: 'items',
                       // rendering inventories
                      inventories: [

                        {
                          id: 1,
                          name: 'tv'
                        },
                        {
                          id: 2,
                          name: 'chair'
                        },
                        {
                          id: 3,
                          name: 'table'
                        },
                      ]
                    }
                  ]

                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

This image to understand where I'm getting this saved indexes

[image]

I have tried to make recursive function but it only gets first array and doesn't go any further to nested arrays

```
  const displayBreadCrumbs = () => {
    let menuKeys = Object.keys(menuIndexes)
    console.log({ menuIndexes });
    console.log(file);
    let arr = []
    let i = 0
    let pathToParse = file


    if (i < menuKeys.length) {
      if (menuKeys[i] in pathToParse) {
        pathToParse = pathToParse[menuKeys[i]][menuIndexes[menuKeys[i]]]
        console.log('pathToParse', pathToParse);
        i = i + 1
        // displayBreadCrumbs()
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: There is no `room_fillings` in the sample data (only in the image) so we can't run this as a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl added room_fillings. Also you can get full json in sandbox in data folder

Comment: Also what is expected result? Get `name` from each item in the path?

Comment: @charlietfl yes, get name from each item in the path using given indexes

Comment: is the result you're after something like `[
  "office",
  "interior",
  "open space",
  "furniture"
]` for the sample data you gave (supposing all indexes are `0` in menuIndexes)

Comment: @NickParsons yes , you right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through each key-value pair object in `menuIndexes` as see which key belongs to the current `pathToParse` object. Once you have the key which applies to the current object, you can access it's associated array as well as the index you need to look at. You can remove the key-value pair from the entries once you've found the key-value pair and again, recursively look for the next key within your new object. You can continue this until you can't find a key from `menuIndexes` which falls into your current `data` object (ie: findIndex returns -1);

```js
const pathToParse = { buildings: [ { name: 'office', building_styles: [ { name: 'interior', rooms: [ { name: 'open space', filling_types: [ { name: 'furniture', inventories: [{ id: 1, name: 'tv' }, { id: 2, name: 'chair' }, { id: 3, name: 'table' }, ] } ] } ] }, ] }, ] }

const menuIndexes = {
  buildings: 0,
  building_styles: 0,
  rooms: 0,
  room_fillings: 0,
  filling_types: 0,
}

function getPath(data, entries) {
  const keyIdx = entries.findIndex(([key]) => key in data);
  if(keyIdx <= -1)
    return [];
    
  const [objKey, arrIdx] = entries[keyIdx];
  const obj = data[objKey][arrIdx];
  entries.splice(keyIdx, 1);
  return [obj.name].concat(getPath(obj, entries)); 
}

console.log(getPath(pathToParse, Object.entries(menuIndexes)));
```

The use of `Object.entries()` is to search the `data` object for the key to look at (as we don't want to rely on the key ordering of the `menuIndexes` object). If you have more control over `menuIndexes`, you could store it in an array where you can safely rely on the ordering of elements and thus keys:

```js
const pathToParse = { buildings: [ { name: 'office', building_styles: [ { name: 'interior', rooms: [ { name: 'open space', filling_types: [ { name: 'furniture', inventories: [{ id: 1, name: 'tv' }, { id: 2, name: 'chair' }, { id: 3, name: 'table' }, ] } ] } ] }, ] }, ] };

const menuIndexes = [{key: 'buildings', index: 0}, {key: 'building_styles', index: 0}, {key: 'rooms', index: 0}, {key: 'filling_types', index: 0}, {key: 'inventories', index: 0}, ];

function getPath(data, [{key, index}={}, ...rest]) {
  if(!key)
    return [];
  const obj = data[key][index];
  return [obj.name, ...getPath(obj, rest)]; 
}

console.log(getPath(pathToParse, menuIndexes));
```

Comment: using Array for `menuIndexes` (instead of Object) is much smarter. Not only Object is not ordered, but some items in the tree could have a duplicate name, making it impossible to represent all breadcumb paths using an Object this way. Array mitigates both problems :D

Answer (score 1):

As usual, I would build such a function atop some reusable parts.  This is my approach:

```js
// Utility functions
const path = (obj, names) =>
  names .reduce ((o, n) => (o || {}) [n], obj)

const scan = (fn, init, xs) => 
  xs .reduce (
    (a, x, _, __, n = fn (a .slice (-1) [0], x)) => [...a, n], 
    [init]
  ) .slice (1)
  
const pluck = (name) => (xs) =>
  xs .map (x => x [name])


// Main function
const getBreadCrumbs = (data, indices) => 
  pluck ('name') (scan (path, data, Object .entries (indices)))


// Sample data
const data = {buildings: [{name: "office", building_styles: [{building_style: 0}, {building_style: 1}, {building_style: 2}, {name: "interior", rooms: [{room: 0}, {room: 1}, {name: "open space", filling_types: [{filling_type: 0}, {name: "furniture", room_fillings: [{name: "items", inventories: [{id: 1, name: "tv"}, {id: 2, name: "chair"}, {id: 3, name: "table"}]}, {room_filling: 1}]}, {filling_type: 2}]}, {room: 3}]}, {building_style: 4}]}]}
const menuIndexes = {buildings: 0, building_styles: 3, rooms: 2, filling_types: 1, room_fillings: 0}


// Demo
console .log (getBreadCrumbs (data, menuIndexes))
```

We have three reusable functions here:

- **`path`** takes an object and  a list of node names (strings or integers) and 
  returns the value at the given path or `undefined` if any node is missing.<sup>1</sup>
  For example:

  ```js
  path ({a: {b: [{c: 10}, {c: 20}, {c: 30}, {c: 40}]}}, ['a', 'b', 2, 'c']) //=> 30.
  ```
- **`scan`** is much like `Array.prototype.reduce`, except that instead of returning
  just the final value, it returns a list of the values calculated at each step.  For 
  example if `add` is `(x, y) => x + y`, then:

  ```js
  scan (add, 0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) //=> [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
  ```
- **`pluck`** pulls the named property off each of a list of objects:

  ```js
  pluck ('b') ([{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30}, {a: 100, b: 200, c: 300}]) 
  //=> [2, 20, 200]
  ```

In practice, I would actually factor these helpers even further, defining `path` in terms of `const prop = (obj, name) => (obj || {}) [name]`, and using `const last = xs => xs.slice (-1) [0]` and `const tail = (xs) => xs .slice (-1)` in defining `scan`.  But that's not important to this problem.

Our main function then can simply use these, along with `Object.entries`<sup>2</sup>, to first grab the entries from your index, passing that, our `path` function, and the data to 
`scan` to get a list of the relevant object nodes, then passing the result to `pluck` along with the string `'name'` that we want to extract.

I use `path` and `pluck` nearly daily.  `scan` is less common, but it's important enough that it's included in my usual utility libraries.  With functions like that easily at hand, it's pretty simple to write something like `getBreadCrumbs`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Side note, I usually define this as `(names) => (obj) => ...`, which I find most commonly useful.  This form happens to fit better with the code used, but it would be easy enough to adapt the code to my preferred form: instead of `scan (path, data, ...)`, we could just write `scan ((a, ns) => path (ns) (a), data, ...)`

<sup>2</sup> As noted in the answer from [Nick Parsons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62245925) and that comment on it from Thankyou, there is a good argument to be made for storing this information in an array, which is explicitly ordered, rather than depending on the strange and arbitrary ordering that general objects get.  If you did that, this code would only change by removing the `Object .entries` call in the main function.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a recursive function like this, it iterates through `menuIndexes` keys and find corresponding object in data. Once it finds the data, it pushes the name into output array and calls the function again with this object and `menuIndexes`

```js
const displayBreadCrumbs = (data, menuIndexes) => {
    const output = [];
    Object.keys(menuIndexes).forEach(key => {
        if (data[key] && Array.isArray(data[key]) && data[key][menuIndexes[key]]) {
            output.push(data[key][menuIndexes[key]].name);
            output.push(...displayBreadCrumbs(data[key][menuIndexes[key]], menuIndexes));
        }
    });
    return output;
};
```

```
const data = { buildings: [ { name: 'office', building_styles: [ { name: 'interior', rooms: [ { name: 'open space', filling_types: [ { name: 'furniture', inventories: [{ id: 1, name: 'tv' }, { id: 2, name: 'chair' }, { id: 3, name: 'table' }, ] } ] } ] }, ] }, ] };

const menuIndexes = {
  buildings: 0,
  building_styles: 0,
  rooms: 0,
  room_fillings: 0,
  filling_types: 0,
};

displayBreadCrumbs(data, menuIndexes); // ["office", "interior", "open space", "furniture"]
```